# Firebase messaging in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I'm new for Xamarin forms, please let me know the process for firebase messaging(push notifications) implementation process and how to achieve this in Xamarin.forms cross platform development.

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't yet supported natively.  Forms requires a specific version of Android Support Libraries = 23.3.0 while Google Play Services - Basement (required by the Firebase component) requires Android Support Libraries >= 24.2.1.  You may be able to patch it through by manually adding the components but NuGet won't allow you to do this and it's not something I'd currently recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services has it Baked in.
See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-push

If you specifically want to use a Firebase hub then
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started should get you started.